# Vim search for a pattern and if it repeats 2nd time delete to end of line

Tags: unix, vim

I'm trying to search for a pattern and if it repeats 2nd time, delete to end of line..., please help.
For that using I'm using `:%s/my_character.*//g`, but this will work for the 1st occurrence of the character in a line, but I need it from 2nd occurrence in the line...

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand it well (you should give a plain example, it always makes it clearer)

I would do it like this:

```
:s/^\(.\{-}my_character.\{-}\)my_character.*$/\1/
```

This will search for:

1. As few character as possible before my_character
2. my_character
3. As few character as possible before the second my_character
4. my_character
5. Any character

And replace it with characters captured from 1 to 3 in the steps above.

---

Example:

Input:

```
werklj z sdkl Azlksd er.
```

search and replace:

```
:s/^\(.\{-}z.\{-}\)z.*$/\1/
```

Output:

```
werklj z sdkl A
```